# Extract every char from each chunk if index modulus 7 == 0

Tags: python, indexing, char, modulus

Ok to I have a list of random letters and numbers that I have spit at ever period so it looks like this

```
text = "adkisnckindlikenskdihjgkiskdik.adkisnckindlikenskdihjgkiskdik.adkisnckindlikenskdihjgkiskdikadkisnckindlikenskdihjgkiskdi."

lines = text.split(".")
for stingssplit in lines:
        print(stingssplit)
```

Now I need to take it's out put:

```
adkisnckindlikenskdihjgkiskdik
adkisnckindlikenskdihjgkiskdik
adkisnckindlikenskdihjgkiskdik
adkisnckindlikenskdihjgkiskdik
```

and Extract every char from each chunk if index modulus 7 == 0

I have no idea what to do?

Comment: [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and the understanding that iterating over a string gives you each character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
text = "adkisnckindlikenskdihjgkiskdik.adkisnckindlikenskdihjgkiskdik.adkisnckindlikenskdihjgkiskdikadkisnckindlikenskdihjgkiskdi."

chunks = text.split(".")

for chunk in chunks:
    print ''.join([v for i, v in enumerate(chunk) if i % 7 == 0])
```

**Output:**

```
>>> for chunk in chunks:
...     print ''.join([v for i, v in enumerate(chunk) if i % 7 == 0])
...
akeji
akeji
akejiniik

>>>
```

**Or in one line:**

```
>>> [''.join([v for i, v in enumerate(chunk) if i % 7 == 0]) for chunk in chunks]
['akeji', 'akeji', 'akejiniik', '']
```

Comment: Yours worked out for me. Thanks, I can now go on to the next part of the script. Thanks again I have been stuck there for a while.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply index it:

```
"adkisnckindlikenskdihjgkiskdik"[::7]
# 'akeji'                 # gives you characters at positions 0, 7, 14, 21, 28
```

---

```
[line[::7] for line in text.split(".")]
# ['akeji', 'akeji', 'akejiniik', '']
```